# Why am i not able to get a legendary item?

Tags: torchlight-2

I am a NG+ level 73 and I am not able to get any legendary item. Is it even possible to get a legendary item even if I am playing at veteran level? Or do i need to have version 1.25.5.2?

Comment: Pls help me this is Reynan a player also of torchlight thank you

Comment: Those tags make no sense at all. If you're talking about torchlight 2 you should say so.

Answer (score 0):

The drops are totally random and its on your luck.
Yes Its possible to get legendary drops on any difficulty settings. The lowest level on which you can receive the legendary drop is 54, which you have achieved already.
[Source](http://torchlight2armory.com/items?item_category=Weapon&quality[]=5#table:items_default%2040%20null%20null%20null%2020)

However if you are really desperate and want to increase the chances of getting the drop then you can try Mods which will increase the drop rate. You can even customize those drop rates and set it to your liking to get more drops.

Here is a Mod for increasing drop chance.
[Increase Drop Rates Mod](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=44051)